# Remove \r\ character from String pattern matched in AWK

Tags: linux, bash, awk, gsub

I'm quite new to AWK so apologies for the basic question. I've found many references for removing windows end-line characters from files but none that match a regular expression and subsequently remove the windows end line characters.

I have a file named infile.txt that contains a line like so:

```
...
DATAFILE   data5v.dat
...
```

Within a shell script I want to capture the filename argument `data5v.dat` from this infile.txt and remove any carriage return character, \r, IF present. The carriage return may not always be present. So I have to match a word and then remove the \r subsequently.

I have tried the following but it is not working how I expect:

```
FILENAME=$(awk '/DATAFILE/ { print gsub("\r", "", $2) }' $INFILE)
```

Can I store the string returned from matching my regex `/DATAFILE/` in a variable within my AWK statement to subsequently apply `gsub`?

Comment: Use `sub(/\r$/,"")`. I use GNU awk and `RS="\r?\n"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File names can contain spaces, including `\r`s, blanks and tabs, so to do this robustly you can't remove all `\r`s with `gsub()` and you can't rely on there being any field, e.g. `$2`, that contains the whole file name.

If your input fields are tab-separated you need:

```
awk '/DATAFILE/ { sub(/[^\t]+\t/,""); sub(/\r$/,""); print }' file
```

or this otherwise:

```
awk '/DATAFILE/ { sub(/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,""); sub(/\r$/,""); print }' file
```

The above assumes your file names don't start with spaces and don't contain newlines.

To test any solution for robustness try:

```
printf 'DATAFILE\tfoo \r bar\r\n' | awk '...' | cat -TEv
```

and make sure that the output looks like it does below:

```
$ printf 'DATAFILE\tfoo \r\tbar\r\n' | awk '/DATAFILE/ { sub(/[^\t]+\t/,""); sub(/\r$/,""); print }' | cat -TEv
foo ^M^Ibar$

$ printf 'DATAFILE\tfoo \r\tbar\r\n' | awk '/DATAFILE/ { sub(/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,""); sub(/\r$/,""); print }' | cat -TEv
foo ^M^Ibar$
```

Note the blank, `^M` (CR), and `^I` (tab) in the middle of the file name as they should be but no `^M` at the end of the line.

If your version of `cat` doesn't support `-T` or `-E` then do whatever you normally do to look for non-printing chars, e.g. `od -c` or `vi` the output.

Answer (score 1):

With `GNU awk`, would you please try the following:

```
FILENAME=$(awk -v RS='\r?\n' '/DATAFILE/ {print $2}' "$INFILE")
echo "$FILENAME"
```

It assigns the record separator `RS` to a sequence of zero or one `\r` followed by `\n`.
As a side note, it is not recommended to use uppercases for user's variable names because it may conflict with system reserved variable names.

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for multi-char RS, it wouldn't work with a POSIX awk.

Answer (score 0):

Awk simply applies each line of script to each input line. You can easily remove the carriage return and then apply some other logic to the input line. For example,

```
FILENAME=$(awk '/\r/ { sub(/\r/, "") }
     /DATAFILE/ { print $2 }' "$INFILE")
```

Notice also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable).

Comment: This did not work. It returned an empty string

Comment: How did you test it? Works for me: `awk '/\r/ { sub(/\r/, "") } /DATAFILE/ { print $2 }' <<<$'hello\r\nthis is DATAFILE\r\ngood bye'` at the Bash prompt prints `is`

Comment: Use infile.txt instead of $INFILE

Comment: The test on the command line works but not when I run it within the shell script? The following is working within the shell script: { sub(/\r/, "", $2); print $2 }. This is from anubhava's comment on the original question

Answer (score 0):

who says you need gnu-awk :

```
 gecho -ne  "test\r\nabc\n\rdef\n" \
 \
 | mawk NF=NF FS='\r' OFS='' | odview

0000000        1953719668      1667391754      1717920778              10
           t   e   s   t  \n   a   b   c  \n   d   e   f  \n            
          164 145 163 164 012 141 142 143 012 144 145 146 012            
           t   e   s   t  nl   a   b   c  nl   d   e   f  nl            
          116 101 115 116  10  97  98  99  10 100 101 102  10            
           74  65  73  74  0a  61  62  63  0a  64  65  66  0a            

0000015
```

gawk -P posix mode is also fine with it :

```
gecho -ne  "test\r\nabc\n\rdef\n" \
\
| gawk -Pe  NF=NF FS='\r' OFS='' | odview

0000000        1953719668      1667391754      1717920778              10
           t   e   s   t  \n   a   b   c  \n   d   e   f  \n            
          164 145 163 164 012 141 142 143 012 144 145 146 012            
           t   e   s   t  nl   a   b   c  nl   d   e   f  nl            
          116 101 115 116  10  97  98  99  10 100 101 102  10            
           74  65  73  74  0a  61  62  63  0a  64  65  66  0a            

0000015
```